# Hide/Unhide Tabs based on Input field (dropdown may be)

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-behavior, user-research

Is there any research for HIDING/UNHIDING Tabs in a page using an input field? I am not sure if it is a good User Experience and Usability.

Comment: This is one of those "IT DEPENDS" questions, there is no answer without more context. In some cases it will be necessary in others it will be disastrous.

Comment: Hi @Garik Thank you for writing on this thread. I will add more info for the context.